# Does "located off to" mean "located closer to"?

Tags: adverbs

[image]

I am trying to describe the positional relationship between the rectangle and the circle in the image.

When my language is literally translated in English, it is described as follows:

> The circle is located off to one corner of the rectangle.

Does the sentence above I created describe the positional relationship in the image correctly?

Comment: Is this really what you are trying to do Is this a picture in a maths problem that you have to describe to someone on the phone? Or are you actually trying to (for example) describe the location of a tree in a garden)  What is the actual task here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How precise do you need to be? I'd just say

> The circle is in the top-left corner of the rectangle.

If I needed to be precise then I'd set up a system of coordinates.

The expression "off to" is used in the phrase "off to one side". This has a negative meaning of "not central".

> The garden has a lawn in the middle and a tree off to one side.

I'd understand "off to one corner", although it isn't a common phrase.